# Photos upload to Azure via WCF Services

Tags: wcf, azure, windows-phone, azure-storage

I have a simple project to upload pics and Images to Azure, I have these strategies

**WINDOWS PHONE -> WCF SERVICE -> AZURE SQL**

**WINDOWS PHONE -> WCF SERVICE -> AZURE STORAGE**

**WINDOWS PHONE -> AZURE STORAGE**

However, I have these questions...

Can I go ahead with WCF Services and if yes, how to deal with large size images?

Maybe better upload from Windows Phone to Azure storage directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that SQL database can be counted off to a large degree. storage is a much more cost effective way to store images which are essentially blobs, however - depending on your needs you might want to store metadata on the blobs in sql to assist in querying

If that is the case using a service layer can assist encapsulating the two paths - storing the blob and storing the metadata

Having said that, passing large blobs through a service is very inefficient and so, for the images themselves, phone->storage is perhaps the most compelling approach and will be the most efficient way to do so both from a coding perspective, solution components and responsiveness; the main downside with that is that it requires the phone app to have the credentials to the storage account, which is a big security risk.

Given all of this you might want to consider a combined flow -> phone->service to store metadata and receive a [shared access signature](http://wely-lau.net/2012/01/10/uploading-file-securely-to-windows-azure-blob-storage-with-shared-access-signature-via-rest-api/) token to the blob and then phone->storage, using the SAS token received, for the photo itself

you will need to handle failures in this flow to update the metadata accordingly...

slightly more complex, but with a good balance between security and performance?

Comment: Check out this code sample which does what Yossi just specified: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Upload-File-to-Windows-c9169190. It uses Windows Azure Mobile Service instead of WCF service but conceptually it's the same thing.